# How to check if an index exists in elasticsearch using a python script and perform exception handling over it?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-net

How do I check whether an index exists or not using a python query?

I'm passing my index as a variable assigned outside the query as :-

```
 i=int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))+1
indextring="index"
for m in range (i-10,i):
    d = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, m, 18, 00).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    index1=datestring+d
    subfix="_"+datetime.datetime(2016, 10, m, 18, 00).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    es=Elasticsearch(['localhost:9200'])
    res = **es.search(index='{0}'.format(index1)**, doc_type="log",size=10000, from_=0, body={ "query": {
    "match": {
     ....Match condition follows
      }
    }
  }})
```

Now, some of the index are not present for a particular date, however I want the process to run irrespective of that. I'm getting the following error when the index is not present-->

**elasticsearch.exceptions.NotFoundError: TransportError(404, u'index_not_found_exception')**

I'm not sure how the exception handling works in elasticsearch.

Comment: You should try using the [`exists` API call](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.exists) to check if an index exists.

Comment: Tried it, can you look at my comment below to tcarmet's reply

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You have to call it on [indices](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#indices). Currently you are using [exists](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.exists) of search class which tells you whether given document exists in the index and not the index itself.

Try this code

```
if es.indices.exists(index="index"):
    Your code for search
```

There are also more [options](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists) if you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in index_list:
    if es.indices.exists(index=i):
        print("ok",i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

to ckeck a list of indexes if they are available or not